# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near... TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What I am trying to do is based on the company_id (@company_id) which has a corresponding database name (@db_name), trying to pull data based on those variables.  I have over 30 tables and need to view data based on which company_id(s) are selected.

i.e. EXEC journal_entries_by_dbase;1'1'

```
    ALTER PROC esh_journal_entries_by_dbase
(@company_id varchar(2))
AS
-------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE ##journal_dbase            
(company_id varchar(8)
, journal_description varchar(255)      
, journal_type varchar(8)
, date_entered varchar(10)
, date_applied varchar(10)
, date_posted varchar(10)
, hold_flag varchar(8)
, reversing_flag varchar(9)
, intercompany_flag varchar(8)
, domain_username varchar(255)
, posted_flag varchar(8)
, multi_currency_flag varchar(8)
, home_credit decimal(20,2)
, home_debit decimal(20,2))
;
-------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE --@company_id varchar(8)
        @db_name varchar(32)
        , @sql varchar(8000)
        , @drop_table varchar(200)
        ;
-------------------------------------------------------
SET @db_name = 'select db_name from contrl.dbo.company where company_id = 1' --@company_id';

-------------------------------------------------------
SET @sql =
'INSERT INTO ##journal_dbase
   SELECT '+@company_id+'  
   , trx.journal_description as [Description]
   , trx.journal_type as [Journal Code]
   , convert(varchar(12),dateadd(dd,(trx.date_entered - 639906),''1/1/1753''),101) as [Entry Date]
   , convert(varchar(12),dateadd(dd,(trx.date_applied - 639906),''1/1/1753''),101) as [Apply Date]
   , convert(varchar(12),dateadd(dd,(trx.date_posted - 639906),''1/1/1753''),101) as [Post Date]
   --, trx.date_entered as [Entry Date]
   --, trx.date_applied as [Apply Date]
   --, trx.date_posted as [Post Date]
   , [Hold] = CASE trx.hold_flag  
        WHEN 0 THEN ''No''  
        WHEN 1 THEN ''Yes'' 
        END --as hold
   , [Trans Flag] = CASE trx.reversing_flag  
        WHEN 0 THEN ''Standard'' 
        WHEN 1 THEN ''Reversing'' 
        END --as trans_flag
   , [InterCo] = CASE trx.intercompany_flag  
        WHEN 0 THEN ''No''  
        WHEN 1 THEN ''Yes''  
        END 
   , CASE WHEN e.domain_username NOT LIKE ''%\%''
        THEN e.domain_username
        ELSE SUBSTRING(e.domain_username,5,20)  --SELECT DISTINCT domain_username FROM ECTRL..smusers
        END AS [User Name]
   , [Posted Flag] = CASE trx.posted_flag  
        WHEN 0 THEN ''No''  
        WHEN 1 THEN ''Yes''  
        END 
   , trx.source_company_code as [Org]
   --, SUM(bal.home_credit) as [Total Home Credit] 
   --, SUM(bal.home_debit) as [Total Home Debit]    
   , bal.home_credit as [Total Home Credit]
   , bal.home_debit as [Total Home Debit]
FROM '+@db_name+'.dbo.trx trx                       
LEFT OUTER JOIN '+@db_name+'.dbo.trxdet trxdet
    ON trx.journal_ctrl_num = trxdet.journal_ctrl_num
LEFT OUTER JOIN '+@db_name+'.dbo.bal bal
    ON trxdet.account_code = bal.account_code
--LEFT OUTER JOIN con.dbo.users e
--  ON trx.user_id = e.user_id
--WHERE trx.date_posted > 0
--  AND trx.date_applied >= ''734503''
--  AND trx.date_applied <= ''734710'''
    ;
-------------------------------------------------------
SET @company_id = 'select company_id from ewcomp' --where db_name in (@db_name)
-------------------------------------------------------
EXEC (@sql);
-------------------------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM ##journal_dbase;
```

THis is returning An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near bal and trx and trxdet.

Comment: Please realise difference between [string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx), executable queries, and [object names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879.aspx).

Comment: is this partial code?  what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: That's not just SQL code, that is part of some code generating SQL code, so what language are you using to do that? Can you also show the SQL code that actually ends up in the string that you create? Also, as the implementation of SQL differs, what kind of database are you using?

Comment: Gserg, appreciate it, but it doesn't help.  Bluefeet, yes, it is partial, I showed the join section of the Stored Proc because that's where the error is coming from.  The rest of the script is pretty lengthy.  I can, from my own knowledge and the obvious error message, understand where the error is coming from.

Comment: This is strictly SQL.  I've used this script elsewhere but with this, I entered the contrl.dbo.company which is throwing me off.  MS SQL 2008.

Comment: Ok... here's the entire script...

Comment: @PuroRock there are a few issues the `@db_name` is being set via dynamic sql but it has not been executed. You then try to use it in your full query. So it doesn't know what the value is.

Comment: @bluefeet: That's exactly what I said in my answer, but you downvoted that?

Comment: @Guffa To be clear, I did not downvote your answer.  I placed it as a comment, because there are other issues with what the OP is doing.

Comment: @bluefeet: Thanks for that at least, but in your comment it sounds like my answer is totally wrong, while it is in fact exactly what you propose yourself. Anyway, what other issues would there be that could cause the syntax error?

Comment: @Guffa i dont think that you provided an actual answer. it could be categorized as a "good catch" but i'm just not sure that it's the answer to the problem.

Comment: @swasheck: Why don't you think that my answer is an actual answer? If the code generates `... FROM select db_name from contrl.dbo.company where company_id = 1.dbo.trx trx ...`, don't you think that's the reason for the syntax error?

Comment: @Guffa without getting into a protracted discussion, i believe that what you're doing is attempting to treat the symptoms and not the problem. having said that, i've *also* not downvoted.

Comment: @swasheck: Thanks for that. I believe that it *is* the reason for the syntax error.

Comment: ...oh, I see what's happening here. Downvotes on my answer, and upvotes on anyone who comments on anything that I say. I know why you are, and you are really showing how childlish you are.

Comment: @PuroRock why are you selecting into `company_id` when that's a parameter that's been passed into the procedure? not that it's affecting anything in the code itself, but it just strikes me as odd. i'm also trying to understand why you're using a temp table in this context?

Comment: Ok, allow me to further explain... within the contrl.dbo.company table, there is a company_id and a corresponding db_name.  Based on the company_id, I want to join on the db_name and pull the data specific to the selected company_id(s).  Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, I feel like an idiot.  The db_name column in the contrl.dbo.company table is identical to the database names I'm trying to join on... so, I believe I need something like this...      `SET @db_name = SELECT db_name FROM contrl.dbo.company WHERE db_name in (SELECT db_name())`

Comment: If anyone out there is even reading this... I can pull the correct dbase using `SELECT name FROM sys.databases 
JOIN contrl.dbo.company 
on sys.databases.name = contrl.dbo.company.db_name 
WHERE contrl.dbo.company.company_id in (@company_id)`.  I just need to know how to bring it in as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was trying to reference internally to the company table to get the `db_name`, when I needed to `JOIN` on it to the `sys.databases`.  I removed the `SET @company_id`  and just used the following for the `@db_name`.  It works.

```
SELECT @db_name = name 
FROM sys.databases 
    JOIN contrl.dbo.company 
    ON sys.databases.name = contrl.dbo.company.db_name 
WHERE contrl.dbo.company.company_id in (@company_id)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are putting the SQL queries in the variables for the company and the database name. I think that you want to query the tables for the values:

```
SET @company = (SELECT company FROM contrl.dbo.company)
SET @db_name = (SELECT db_name FROM contrl.dbo.company WHERE company = @company)
```

Or simply:

```
SELECT @company = company FROM contrl.dbo.company
SELECT @db_name = db_name FROM contrl.dbo.company WHERE company = @company
```

---

#### Edit:

With your updated code; change this:

```
SET @db_name = 'select db_name from contrl.dbo.company where company_id = 1'
```

to

```
SELECT @db_name = db_name from contrl.dbo.company where company_id = 1
```

or with the @CompnayId variable:

```
SELECT @db_name = db_name from contrl.dbo.company where company_id = cast(@CompanyId as int)
```

Comment: This will only work if there is only one row on the `company` table.

Comment: This will not work if the the table has more than one row that meets the criteria.  How do you advise resolving that?

Comment: @Lamak & bluefeet: You are missing the point completely. Of course this only works if there is only one record in the table, but if the variable contains a SQL query instead of the actual data, it won't work at all to use it to create another query.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.